# jquery mobile scroll to top when scrolling back

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, mobile

i have a problem with jquery mobile. I have a long DOM with many li elements but it isn't a listview. When i scroll down everything works fine, but when i scroll a little bit up, the page jumps to the top of the page. Have some one an idea how i handle that?

The effect is only on my smartphone, with the chrome browser.

Thanks.

I tried to update the layout of the ui-content. But it doesn't help.

```
 $( ".ui-content" ).trigger( "updatelayout" );
```

I think when i scroll some px to the top the window size is changed by the displayed navbar of chrome and than the page jumps to the top.

Comment: Maybe you unterstand me wrong. I don't want to scroll or jump to the top. I want do prevent it. When my DOM on my site is long and i scroll i little bit top, the scroll position jumps to the beginning of the page. And i don't know why. The only idea i have on mobile devices the navbar of the browser is showing on scrolling up. This change the window height and maybe jquery mobile trigger something on this.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.silentScroll/) I found one way for the issue by using the `jQuery.mobile.silentScroll()` in jQuery Mobile which scrolls to a particular Y position without triggering scroll event listeners. This method does not perform animated scrolling.

```
<script>
        $(document).on('click', '.returnTopAction', function() {
            $.mobile.silentScroll(0);
        });
    </script>
```

Also you can use the code below which allows animated scrolling:

```
<script>
        $(document).on('click', '.returnTopAction', function() {
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#arealistpage").offset().top}, 1000);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Maybe you unterstand me wrong. I don't want to scroll or jump to the top. I want do prevent it. When my DOM on my site is long and i scroll i little bit top, the scroll position jumps to the beginning of the page. And i don't know why. The only idea i have on mobile devices the navbar of the browser is showing on scrolling up. This change the window height and maybe jquery mobile trigger something on this.